# how to add text (shell var.) in the first place in each line using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am using `sed` in `bash shell script`. I want to add some text, which is defined as shell variable, in the first place of each line using `sed`.

For example,

```
cat filename
1.cfg
2.cfg
...
100.cfg
```

In the script,

```
#!/bin/bash
currentd="/home/test/"
sed "/WHAT SHOUL I DO to add $currentd/" filename > filepath
```

I want to add the file path `currentd` in the first place of the each line in `filename` and get `filepath` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed "s|^|$currentd|" filename > filepath
```

This "replaces" the start of each line (`^`) with `$currentd`. This requires that `$currentd` not contain any pipes (`|`).

Comment: Could you explain the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using `awk`, as:

```
awk -v c=$currentd '{print c $0}' filename > filepath
```

`-v` is used to set `awk` variable `c` to bash variable `currentd`.